# mysql php select random with javascript rotator

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I just started learning PHP, and have been trying to build a website to learn. I found a javascript script that rotates text on the internet [here](http://www.javascriptbank.com/random-text-rotator-script.html/en/) which looks like:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">

    function rotateEvery(sec)
    {
    var Quotation=new Array()

    // QUOTATIONS
    Quotation[0] = 'First quotation';
    Quotation[1] = 'Second quotation';
    Quotation[2] = 'Third quotation';
    Quotation[3] = 'Fourth quotation';
    Quotation[4] = 'Fifth quotation';
    Quotation[5] = 'Sixth quotation';
    Quotation[6] = 'You can add <b>as many</b> quotations <b>as you like</b>';

    var which = Math.round(Math.random()*(Quotation.length - 1));
    document.getElementById('textrotator').innerHTML = Quotation[which];

    setTimeout('rotateEvery('+sec+')', sec*1000);
    }
</script>
```

I also have a database table called events that has three fields ( id, when, tag) When is a date, tag is the description of the event (e.g Christmas Party/Halloween at my house).

What i am trying to do is select the events that are happening today and put them in my javascript rotator, randomly.

Is this possible? How would I go about implementing this? I know I am really bad at explaining my questions so if I left out any more details if you could just tell me and I can help.Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible. What you tried in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand your intent, you want to pull events from your database and pass them into the JavaScript on your page to use in your rotator:

#### In your PHP

Use whichever MySQL API you are using already to execute the query.  Using the old `mysql_*()` functions would look like the following. (*Note: use of the `mysql_*()` functions is actually NOT recommended, but it seems most likely that's what you're currently using. I'll update if I find out otherwise...*)

```
// Assuming `when` is a real DATE or DATETIME data type in MySQL...
// compare to CURDATE() to get today's
$result = mysql_query("SELECT tag FROM events WHERE DATE(when)=CURDATE()");
if ($result) {
  // array to hold all the output
  $events = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Add the event to your array
    $events[] = $row['tag'];
  }
  // After building the array, encode it as JSON
  // Later you'll echo this into your JavaScript in place of the array...
  $events = json_encode($events);
}
```

#### Later in your HTML/JavaScript output

Output the JSON string (your array) into the JavaScript on your page:

```
function rotateEvery(sec)
{
  // The JSON from PHP output here
  // Would look something like
  // ["Event 1","Event 2","Event 3"]
  var Quotations = <?php echo $events; ?>;

  var which = Math.round(Math.random()*(Quotation.length - 1));
  document.getElementById('textrotator').innerHTML = Quotation[which];

  setTimeout('rotateEvery('+sec+')', sec*1000);
}
```

Comment: Is there problems with mysql_*() function? Should I not use it?

Comment: See [the manual](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).  They are deprecating the old mysql_*() functions in favor of the newer APIs like PDO and MySQLi, which support prepared statements for much improved security.